# Why can't I log-in in my Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I logged in at minecraft.net and I opened my Minecraft launcher. After I logged in, it said "login failed". I am sure the username and password is correct but it says "login failed". Why?

Comment: I don't think we should be duping to a closed question.

Answer (score 3):

There area few things that could be causing this:

1. Your Internet connection is faulty.
2. One or more of Minecraft's servers is down. You can check by [clicking here](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/) or by [clicking here.](http://help.mojang.com/)
3. You are not logging in with your Mojang account. When you make a Minecraft account, you are actually making a Mojang account, and buying Minecraft *for* the Mojang account. Make sure you use your Mojang username to log in. Your Mojang username *should* be an E-mail address.

   **Example**:

   > Username: `JohnSmith@gmail.com`
   >   Password: `SecretPassword`

   *not*

   > Username: `JohnTheMinecraftDude`
   >   Password: `SecretPassword`
4. You are not premium. Did you pay for Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

It is either your internet connection or Mojang's servers. Try again after a few hours.